# Visual studio custom build step rule?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, custom-build-step

Using Visual Studio 2008, When I add to a C++ project a file that is not `.c/.cpp/.h/.rc` or anything the IDE doesn't recognize a dialog pops up which asks me if I want to create a custom build step rule for this kind of files.

Does anybody know how to get to this dialog without adding a file? I can't seem to be able to find in any of the menus.

---

Edit: I know all about the `.rules` file. What I'm talking about is a GUI Dialog from within Visual Studio 2008 which allows you to create and edit these `.rules` files. This is the dialog I mentioned which pops up when you add a file with an unknown extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add an item with an unknown extension, you'll get a message box titled "Matching Custom Build Rule Not Found", which asks if you'd like to create a new rule file to define a custom build rule to build files with that extension.  If you click "Yes", you'll get the "New Rule File" dialog.

If you'd like to just get that same "New Rule File" dialog:

1. Right-click your project
2. Select "Custom Build Rules..."
3. Click the button "New Rule File..."

If you're asking how to get the "Matching Custom Build Rule Not Found" message box itself, I'm not sure how you'd do that.  (If that's what you're trying to do, you may want to clarify that in your question)

Comment: I got all that. What I want to know is how to simply set the build rule to copy the file to the Output directory and to have this as a post-build step so it only runs if the build succeeded.