# "Copy to Output Directory" in a C++/CLI Project

Tags: visual-studio, ide

How do I get the "Copy to Output Directory" property for content files in a C++/CLI Windows Forms Project?

[image]

**Edit:** I am presently using the post-build event to copy my content files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the projects property pages, use the post build events to trigger a bat or command file to copy the file(s) to the output directory.

See here MSDN article on [Build Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx)

**Edit**

Have you checked out this question [Visual studio custom build step rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502194/visual-studio-custom-build-step-rule/514060)
Sounds like it might work for you, setup a custom build step (i.e. file copy) and associate it with the file types of your custom content files.

Then when you add another file you don't need to modify the post build step.
I don't do much C++ any more and I didn't know you could do this, nice to know it's there though.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Build events is what I am using at the moment. Was looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: I have checked all of these and it's obvious it needs a custom build step but nobody is saying anywhere what you put in it. If the build step command is copy, what are its parameters? What goes in Outputs?

Comment: @CashCow: Sounds like you need to ask a new question. Sorry.

Comment: I found the answer from someone on our chat channel at work. There were several steps I had to do.

Comment: @CashCow What were those steps?