# Question about Cyclone

Tags: visual-studio

I have read [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclone_(programming_language)) that the Cyclone programming language is a safe dialect of the C programming language so consider the following C code.

```
int strlen(const char *s)
{
    int iter = 0;
    if (s == NULL) return 0;
    while (s[iter] != '\0') {
        iter++;
    }
    return iter;
}
```

This function assumes that the string being passed in is terminated by NUL ('\0').
But if we pass a string like this,

```
char buf[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','!'}
```

it would cause `strlen` to iterate through memory not necessarily associated with the string s. So there is another version of this code in Cyclone

```
int strlen(const char ? s)
{
    int iter, n = s.size;
    if (s == NULL) return 0;
    for (iter = 0; iter < n; iter++, s++) {
       if (*s == '\0') return iter;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Can I use Cyclone in Visual Studio or do I have to donwload a new compiler?

Answer (score 3):

You will need [Cyclone](http://cyclone.thelanguage.org/wiki/The%20compiler). It is also the name of the compiler. The Cyclone compiler is available in source code [here](http://cyclone.thelanguage.org/wiki/Download). The Cyclone compiler can, according to the documentation, only be compiled with GCC. Check [this](http://cyclone.thelanguage.org/wiki/Installing%20Cyclone) to compile the Cyclone compiler.

You can use it from Visual Studio if you provide [custom rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502194/visual-studio-custom-build-step-rule) for the *.cyc files. This way you can use the IDE as a better text editor. For syntax highlighting and style assign *.cyc to the C language extention list.

Answer (score 2):

You can run custom tools for a file with a specific filename extension.  The MSDN Library article on how to setup the custom build rule [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsbz6cw%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Beware that this is pretty broken in VS2010 right now.